# Modeling Wildlife Survey Data with Conditional Outcomes

Tags: predictive-models, multivariate-analysis, interpretation, structural-equation-modeling, generalized-additive-model

I'm working on a project involving surveying for an invasive species which is removed upon encounter. When an individual is encountered, morphometrics are collected (e.g., size and sex). I'm interested in predicting which survey conditions result in the highest likelihood of removal for specific demographics.  Survey conditions are collected on every survey and include variables like survey duration and temperature. Here's a simplified example of the data structure:

| SurveyID | Temp | Duration | Capture | Size | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 3 | 0 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 25 | 2 | 1 | 5.2 | M |
| 2 | 25 | 2 | 1 | 4.8 | F |
| 3 | 27 | 4 | 1 | 5.5 | M |
| 4 | 23 | 2 | 0 | NA | NA |
| 5 | 28 | 3 | 1 | 5.7 | M |
| 5 | 28 | 3 | 1 | 4.9 | F |

In this table, "Capture" indicates whether an animal was captured (1) or not (0), and "Size" and "Sex" are recorded only for captured animals. Note that SurveyID 2 and 5 include multiple captures, demonstrating a survey with more than one capture, whereas SurveyIDs 1 and 4 show surveys with no captures.

Given these considerations, I'm unsure which modeling approach would be most appropriate for my objectives, which include predicting the effects of survey conditions on the probability of encounter, as well as predicted the demographics of encountered individuals. The reason this approach is necessary is some demographics (e.g., large females) have a disproportionate impact on population recruitment and growth. Thus, optimizing survey practices to remove these individuals is likely to facilitate managment objectives.

Given this situation, which modeling approach may be well situated for this kind of conditional, multivariate data?

I've considered GAMs but I don't think they would handle the conditional nature of the multivariate response well. I am interested in possibly applying Structural Equation Modeling to the problem but am unsure about their interpretability which is important when describing results to stakeholders.  Has anyone tackled similar challenges or can share insights on using SEM in this context?